# How to return the coordinates of a region in an image and its dimension in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two datasets, both of which have 25 x 25 dimensions. One dataset is the "full" image and the second dataset shows an object in the first image, which means everything outside of the object is a zero.

How do I return the coordinates of where the object in the second dataset exists so it can be applied found in the first dataset?

And how I do find the dimensions of where the object exists (the height and width of the object in the numpy array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the 'full' image `img` and the object label image `mask`. I'll use 5 × 5 arrays for illustration:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.random((5, 5))
mask = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       ], dtype=bool)
```

Then you can easily get the area of `True` points in the mask: it's just the sum because `True` is 1 and `False` is 0:

```
np.sum(mask)
```

You can get the coordinates where `mask` is `True` with `np.argwhere(mask)`, but in practice you probably don't need to because you can just index into `img` directly using `mask`. That is, you can get the data from `img` where `mask` is `True` like so:

```
img[mask]
```

So for example, you can get the mean of data points where `mask` is `True` like so:

```
np.mean(img[mask])
```

You can get `img` with only the masked data, letting everything else be 0:

```
img * mask
```

Or if you prefer `nan`s for the masked-off areas:

```
masked = img.copy()
masked[~mask] = np.nan
```

Finally, you can get the `[height, width]` of the masked area like so:

```
[np.sum(np.max(mask, axis=i)) for i in (1, 0)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the coordinate of the center of the object?

Comment: Anything is possible! The easiest thing is just to take the mean (or some sort of centrality measure) of all the row and column indices. But it depends a bit what you mean by 'center'... for example, does the center have to be inside the object?

Comment: I figured it out. There is a simple function in Scipy where you can find the coordinate of the "mass" of an object, and since there is only one object, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @kdf - nice! Good solution.